# How/Where to execute a golang binary that generates svg

Tags: svg, go

I'm trying to learn Golang by making my way through [The Go Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134190440). I'm on Ch3 and there's an example prgramming that, to quote the book:

> plots a function of two variables z = f(x, y) as a wire mesh 3-D surface.

When I execute the program it generates something like this:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style='stroke: grey; fill: white; stroke-width: 0.7' width='600' height='320'><polygon points='302.5980762113533,6.408069589119515 300,5.765251108350995 297.4019237886467,6.408069589119515 300,7.256408337069842'/>
<polygon points='300,7.256408337069842 297.4019237886467,6.408069589119515 294.80384757729337,7.2672587589197954 297.4019237886467,8.356773520066966'/>
<polygon points='297.4019237886467,8.356773520066966 294.80384757729337,7.2672587589197954 292.20577136594005,8.368149318273655 294.80384757729337,9.724223435392517'/>
<polygon points='294.80384757729337,9.724223435392517 292.20577136594005,8.368149318273655 289.60769515458674,9.724590598214316 292.20577136594005,11.361343197756081'/> 

... many more polygon points

</svg>
```

Further on in the chapter there are exercises concerning modifying this program so I'd like to run it and get a proper graphical output instead of just a printout of all the points.

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated. So far I've only tried running the program in iTerm.

**Edit**

I've also tried running it in the Go playground in Chrome.

Comment: A SVG file _si_ a "proper graphical output". Just view it in any appropriate program, e.g. a browser.

Comment: And how do I open a golang program in a browser? I'm pretty sure I can't just drag and drop the executable.

Comment: @SoSimple: you don't open golang program in a browser. You run the program in a terminal, it generates you a file, you then open _that file_ in a browser.

Comment: Maybe I need to modify it then to print to a file. As it is the program doesn't generate a file, it just prints out a load of polygon points. I thought there may have been some way for me to run it just as it is. Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @SoSimple: no need to modify the program. If it spits proper svg content to stdout, that's enough. Redirect that output into a file: `./my_program > file.svg`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much @SergioTulentsev. If you put it in an answer I'll gladly accept/approve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the resulting SVG, you need to open it (as a file) in a SVG viewer (a browser, for example). The easiest way to save that output into a SVG file is to redirect the output of your program into a file:

```
./my_program > file.svg
```

Now you can double-click `file.svg` and see your chart.